# Raw format of \pdfcreationdate?

Tags: pdf, date

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\pdfcreationdate % LuaLaTeX: {\pdffeedback creationdate}
\end{document}
```

The above prints a string like this (I am in Pacific Standard time zone, which is -8h):

```
D:20171206082501-08’00’
```

I understand the content of the above string. My question concerns details of the raw string format. I am not asking how to re-format it, because there are packages, such as `datetime2`, which will do that.

1. From the perspective of TeX tokens and catcodes and whatnot, is there anything special about the `D:` prefix? Same with the other non-numeric characters.
2. The print shows the quotemarks as curly, but I presume that they are ordinary straight quotes in the raw string, yes?
3. Now for the hard part: It is my understanding that Western Hemisphere time zones are preceded by a minus sign, and Eastern Hemisphere time zones are preceded by a plus sign. It is not clear what happens in Greenwich time zone. Is it +00'00' ? I dug into the code of file `pdfx.sty` and it seems that there is a third case, in which Greenwich time is shown as `Z` or something similar. Is that the case?

Why I want to know: I already have code (from someone else) that manipulate the `\pdfcreationdate` string, but does so in a very opaque manner. I would like to re-code it so that the coding is more readable by future maintainers. But I'm not confident of the exact string provided by `\pdfcreationdate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of the date string comes from the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), see section "7.9.4 Dates".

1. The category codes are the same as the result of `\string` or `\detokenize`. All characters except the space have category code 12 (other). The space has category code 10 (space).
2. The "quotemark" is an ASCII character: APOSTROPHE (U+0027)
3. The `Z` is a shortcut for the [Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time), from the PDF specification:

   > the LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z signifies that local time is equal to UT.

Comment: Excellent. I did not realize that the string format was directly from the PDF Reference (which I have). Thought it was a TeX-internal thing.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to extract the code from the `\pdfcreationdate` that works in all engines; with XeLaTeX it only provides year, month, day, hour and minute.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_getdate_data_prop
\str_new:N \g_getdate_pdfdate_str
\cs_if_exist:NTF \pdfcreationdate
 {
  \str_gset:Nx \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { \pdfcreationdate }
 }
 {
  \cs_if_exist:NTF \pdffeedback
   {
    \str_gset:Nx \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { \pdffeedback creationdate }
   }
   {
    \str_gset:Nx \g_getdate_pdfdate_str
     {
      D:
      \int_eval:n { \c_sys_year_int }
      \int_compare:nT { \c_sys_month_int < 10 } { 0 }
      \int_eval:n { \c_sys_month_int }
      \int_compare:nT { \c_sys_day_int < 10 } { 0 }
      \int_eval:n { \c_sys_day_int }
      \int_compare:nT { \c_sys_hour_int < 10 } { 0 }
      \int_eval:n { \c_sys_hour_int }
      \int_compare:nT { \c_sys_minute_int < 10 } { 0 }
      \int_eval:n { \c_sys_minute_int }
     }
   }
 }

\prop_gput:Nnx \g_getdate_data_prop { year }
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { 3 } { 6 }
 }
\prop_gput:Nnx \g_getdate_data_prop { month }
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { 7 } { 8 }
 }
\prop_gput:Nnx \g_getdate_data_prop { day }
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { 9 } { 10 }
 }
\prop_gput:Nnx \g_getdate_data_prop { hour }
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { 11 } { 12 }
 }
\prop_gput:Nnx \g_getdate_data_prop { minute }
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { 13 } { 14 }
 }
\prop_gput:Nnx \g_getdate_data_prop { second }
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { 15 } { 16 }
 }
\prop_gput:Nnx \g_getdate_data_prop { diff }
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { 17 } { 17 }
 }
\prop_gput:Nnx \g_getdate_data_prop { hourdiff }
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { 18 } { 19 }
 }
\prop_gput:Nnx \g_getdate_data_prop { minutediff }
 {
  \str_range:Nnn \g_getdate_pdfdate_str { 21 } { 22 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getdatestring}{}
 {
  \str_use:N \g_getdate_pdfdate_str
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getdate}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_getdate_data_prop { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\gettimedifference}{}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \prop_item:Nn \g_getdate_data_prop {diff} } { Z }
   {
    0
   }
   {
    $\prop_item:Nn \g_getdate_data_prop {diff}$
    \prop_item:Nn \g_getdate_data_prop {hourdiff}
    :
    \prop_item:Nn \g_getdate_data_prop {minutediff}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The year is \getdate{year}, the time is \getdate{hour}:\getdate{minute}
and the time difference with UTC is \gettimedifference

The full string is \getdatestring

\end{document}
```

Additional macros for extracting the various pieces of information in a more friendly way can be defined.

Output with my time zone:

[image]

Output with UTC time zone:

[image]

Comment: The case UTC with `Z` as difference to UTC is missing. (Test/bash: `TZ=UTC pdflatex ...`)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek It's easy to define a `\gettimedifference` to cope with the case.

Comment: @egreg this now gives `<argument> \LaTeX3 error:` with `'\str_if_eq_x:nnTF' deprecated on 2020-01-01. Use...` and `l.98 ... difference with UTC is \gettimedifference`

Comment: @hsmyers Fixed! Thanks for noting.

Comment: @egreg Doesn't seem to handle negative offsets?

Comment: @hsmyers I tried with `TZ='America/Los_Angeles' pdflatex getdate` and got the expected result with `-08:00` (`getdate.tex` is the file name for the code example).

Comment: @egreg Didn't think to set TZ hence got nothing for that end of the string—duh!

Comment: @egreg  TZ set to America/Boise and yet nothing but `UTC is:` at the end of the line?

Comment: @hsmyers Sorry, but I get `UTC is -07:00`. Are you using XeLaTeX, perchance? Because it is not supported, not having the facility.

Comment: @egreg Yes I am…just checked with pdflatex and all is well!

Comment: @hsmyers The first paragraph of the answer is clear, I believe. Sorry, but it's not currently possible, unless one uses `-shell-escape` to access the appropriate shell command.

Comment: @egreg No problem, stumbled across another way around the problem using `\usepackage{texosquery}` which means `datetime2` works without a problem.

Comment: @egreg I super appreciate that you wrote this to detect whether the primitive exists rather than hard-coding to the name of the engine! It just works now with XeTeX! ♥